# Efficient Chatroom Backend?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, backend, chatroom

I am currently trying to find the best way to write an IM chat application that is cross compatible with both iOS and android.

The idea is that user registers to the app and is then randomly paired with other users within the application the chat is 1 on 1.

Like mentioned I want this to be cross platform however I was thinking of only making it for iOS to begin with, however I want the ability to extend this to android for the future.

The main issue is that I want to create something that is scalable. When this is finished it should be able to support 100 user seamlessly but at least has the option to be scaled further in the future.

I’m currently researching are XMPP and NodeJS I originally thought these were for more whatsApp group chat applications however ive recently discovered Tinders backend is NodeJS. The user data storage (registered info eg: age, sex) would be done in mySQL and PHP. I am also thinking PHP to connect users.

I was originally thinking of writing a web application(HTML 5), then making an iOS app with a webView and simply linking the application to the webView.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Crib notes
randomly assigned 1 on 1 chats (think tinder no contact lists group chat etc)
Ability to be scaled maintaining efficiency
Ability to be cross platform (Android added later)